# HTML height not working for my table, it doesn't show on all my web browser

Tags: html, height

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="100%">
<header style="border-style:solid">Sukhesh web page</header>
<tr>
<td>id
<td>name
<td>address
```

Please help me how to take default height of every browser when I run this html page

Comment: You haven't closed out the table. Your syntax is incorrect https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: i'm sorry i closed my table in my IDE but not here, i just want to know the problem in my code

Comment: You haven't closed any of your tags. Please post the correct code to get an accurate diagnostic of your problem.

Comment: Update your question please. Comments aren't very useful in viewing code

Comment: I'm sorry sir it says i have reached the question limit, please understand my situation and help me with the comments

Comment: Like I said. Your table syntax is incorrect. I will post the correct syntax in the answer. Accept it as the answer if it helps you. Cheers

Comment: That sounds great, thanks for helping

Comment: @GopaluniSukhesh Editing your question shouldn't have any question limits.

Comment: i got it, when i write bottom=0; and top=0; in head then i got it

Comment: @GopaluniSukhesh [edit] your question please

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid. 
You should use `thead` for your header and `tbody` for your body.

Here is a live example.

```html
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1"> 
  <thead style="border-style:solid">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" >Sukhesh web page</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr> 
    <td>id </td>
    <td>name </td>
    <td> address </td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXPQdO

Cheers and happy coding.

Comment: Did this work? This is a standard table and will show up in any browser.